# basic C programming Game of Life

Tags: c, windows

I have a problem with my code. I have a dynamic frame sized by the user and he needs to input the position of one cell in this frame. My question is, how can I make sure that this position is valid or if it hasn't been entered yet?

Here's the code:

```
for (i = 0; i < a; i++)
{
    while (x < 1 || y < 1)
    {
        printf("Entrez les coordonnees de la cellule %d: ", i+1); //The user gives the position of the cell
        scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);
    }

    tab[x - 1][y - 1] = 1; //We affect 1 to the cell given by the user
}
```

Comment: What constitutes a valid position? One where `x` and `y` are `>=0` and `<` the size of each dimension of `tab`? Already entered is `== 1`? If so, then that should be pretty simple for you to solve.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `memset` to set the whole `tab` matrix to zero,

so that when you want to see if the user already entered this coordinate,

you do `if(tab[x-1][y-1] != 0)`, as for making sure the coordinates are valid, you could make

```
while(true){
   ....
   scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);
   if(x > 1 && x < X_MAX && y > 1 && y < Y_MAX){
     if(tab[x-1][y-1] != 0)
        printf("This coordinate was already typed.\n");
     else
        break;
    }
 }
 tab[x-1][y-1] = 1;
```

Where X_MAX and Y_MAX spcifies the maximum boundary (size) of your `tab` matrix

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the sizes of `tab` are N and M respectively you can do:

```
if (x < 0 || x>= N || y < 0 || y >= M) {
  printf("O-oh fell out of the field\n!");
  .. do stuff ...
}
```

As for whether a field has already been entered you will have to device an algorithm to remember which fields have already been entered. Either create one more matrix with boolean values indicating if a field has already been entered, or use some hash table to store entered pair of coordinates.